# favicon.ico not supported under Windows IIS

Tags: iis, favicon

We have a problem under Microsoft IIS. People are not able to request the favicon through the browser. We checked all the coding of the website we are hosting on it and it is all fine. Problem is that the icon file seems to be blocked in general for the outside world:

Icon location: http://www.raakbeleving.nl/favicon.ico (gives 404)

Anybody any clue what could make this happen?
Our hosting provider cannot seem to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of IIS? What do the IIS logs report?

Comment: Hi G_P, problem is that I cannot see that as I'm not the server admin. Problem is that the server provider doesn't know what is wrong and I'm trying to figur out what this could be. As we already have this issie for 2 months now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28WS.10%29.aspx) for a way to set up the content type in IIS 7.

[Here](http://www.favicon.com/ie.html) there are a number of additional hints for it..

Answer (score 0):

MS IIS Manager version 1809 includes a MIME type of .ico

**To Clarify the Problem:  **

I have my favicon.ico in the root directory of my application which has an alias name of the website.  I have run the same html through a number of servers. Each one looks for the favicon.ico, finds it, and uses it.

When you access a website without a favicon.ico, the icon on the browser tab for that site will have a browser default icon.  The favicon.ico, when it exists, will replace that tabl icon with a custom one.  I have found a lot of sites that discuss how MS IIS does not support favicon.ico.